# Enum Values return as json in Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have model called location with one enum location _type. My model implemented like below

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum location_type: [:Offshore, :Onsite]

end
```

This work correctly for mapping insertion and display. But now i want an action to give the enum as json for binding to the drop down in the client side. Please help me to do this

Edit:

Now i read [this](http://viget.com/extend/how-to-implement-an-enumerated-type-in-rails) articles expected like this only. But i just copt and created Enum class and LocationType class in the lib directory (with out any module nmae). But how i do this in controller action. I got NameError. My controller is

```
class Api::V1::LocationsController < Api::V1::BaseController


  def get_location_types

    Rails.logger.warn(LocationType.values)

    #respond_with Location.location_types.to_json


  end
```

Comment: location_type.to_json doesn't work?

Comment: sorry i am new to this. Please give how we create this as action in the controller with routes. I think this is my issue

Comment: yes i got but i want like value and and name